# Installation Sqlcmd: Error - The client cannot connect to the server because the requested instance was not available

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation, sql-database

I'm trying to install `Sitecore 9.1 Update 1` on my local machine. The script actually installs 7 databases like (MarketingAutomation, Messaging, Reporting), however when it comes to Sitecore databases it fails.

I did install the Prerequisites also the `Microsoft Common Line Utilities` for SQL server.

#### Below is the error message

```
[--------------------------------------------------- XConnectXP0_CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLoginSqlCmd : Command -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
[Command]:[Path] sqlcmd
SQLCMD.EXE : Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : The client cannot connect to the server because the requested instance was not available. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to make sure the SQL Server 
instance is configured correctly. .
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-CommandTask.ps1:31 char:13
+             & $Path $Arguments | Out-Default
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Sqlcmd: Error: ...ed correctly. .:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command sqlcmd returned a non-zero exit code - (1)
At C:\Resourcefiles\Sitecore9_1_1\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:74 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:03:17
Invoke-CommandTask : Command sqlcmd returned a non-zero exit code - (1)
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:25
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-CommandTask
```

Answer (score 0):

The server or local machine where Sitecore installation is running there might be a `SQL server management studio 2016 SP2 or 2017` version not installed correctly. If it was installed then please check the system environment variable path where  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\` is the location of `sqlcmd exe`

Microsoft SQL Server Drivers and Utilities You must also install:

- Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
- Microsoft Command Line Utilities 13 for SQL Server SQL Server

Restart your machine and try to re-run the script.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the issue. It was related to the SQL instance name.

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/20243/4050